# Enable Message Tracking on Edge Server for Non-Admins

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I am trying to do some message tracking on our Exchange 2010 Edge server and I find that in order to use it, I have to start the Exchange Management Shell as an administrator otherwise I get an access denied error.  This Windows Server 2008R2 machine sits in the DMZ and is not domain joined.  I am guessing that this has something with RBAC but those commands don't exist on the Edge server so I don't know how to set it up.  Could someone explain how to configure this?  Also, is it possible to allow access from a remote workstation?